# Как подключиться к онлайн MySQL из локального сервера

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Всем привет.

Есть локальный сервер в OpenServer и база данных, которая предоставлена хостинг-компанией.

При попытке соединить их между собой на странице появляется это:

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ����������. in H:\OSPanel\domains\test-mysql\index.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ����������. in H:\OSPanel\domains\test-mysql\index.php on line 5

Код:

```
<?php


$sql = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'database');


$sql->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

?>
```

Этот самый код пробовал запускать на онлайн хостинге - РАБОТАЕТ.

Так что ошибок быть не может.
С OpenServer'ом все ок, так как к локальной базе он подключается без проблем.

Вопрос именно в соединении локального сервера с онлайн MySQL.

Возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Конечно возможно. Обращайтесь к хостинг-провайдеру. Может у них MySQL-сервер вообще извне недоступен

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо!

Comment: Никакой хостер в здравом уме не разрешит подключаться к серверной БД скриптами извне. Эт ж че угодно можно в БД натворить и концов не найдешь потом.